# AngularJS Http Post - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I know there's a lot of other `500 (Internal Server Error)` questions out there, but reading them is still not helping my case.

I am working on two angularjs methods that have `$http post` calls in them.

**FIRST PROBLEM**

The first successfully hits the server-side controller, and returns a JSON object as I expect it, but my drop downs are not being filled by the result of the factory call.

One thing that concerns me, is the console output. (As you'll see in the code below I have several print statements.) The URL is printed, and then my drop down options field is printed as `undefined`, and then the response from the server comes back with the response. Do I need to tell the JS to wait for the response? Some sort of ASYNC?

[image: Drop Downs not Loading]

**SECOND PROBLEM**

I have the exact same `http post` method call (but with new variables), and I get the `500 (Internal Server Error)` error message. The server-side ctrl method is not being hit for this call (based on break point in ctrl).

[image: 500 Error]

**Questions**

1. How do I fill my drop down successfully with the result of the
   `$http.post` call?
2. Why is my second `$http.post` method creating the `500 (Internal Server Error)`?

**Javascript**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('LineModule', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller("LineCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', 'LineService',
function ($scope, $http, LineService) {
    $scope.Types = LineService.get_DropDownList("Type");
    console.log("Types:"); console.log($scope.Types);
    $scope.Statuses = LineService.get_DropDownList("Status");
    $scope.FundingSources = LineService.get_DropDownList("Funding_Source");
    ...

    $scope.get_DeptLeader = function () {
        $scope.SelectedLeader = LineService.get_DeptLeader($scope.CPOC_Title, $scope.CostCenter_ID);
    };

}]);

app.factory('LineService', ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
        ...


        ***FIRST METHOD***
        get_DropDownList: function (field) {
            var info = {
                section: 'Line',
                field: field
            };

            var URL = getBaseURL() + 'DBO/DropDown_GetList';
            console.log(URL);
            var DropDown;
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: URL,
                data: JSON.stringify(info),
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response !== 'undefined' && typeof (response) == 'object') {
                    DropDown = response.data;
                    console.log(DropDown);
                    return DropDown;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('ERROR:');
                    console.log(response);
                    return 'No Options Found';
                }
            });
        },


        ***SECOND METHOD***
        get_DeptLeader: function (CPOC_Title, CostCenter_ID) {
            console.log("call get leader");

            if (CPOC_Title < 1 || CPOC_Title == undefined) { return "No Title Selected"; }
            if (CostCenter_ID < 1 || CostCenter_ID == undefined) { return "No Cost Center Selected"; }

            console.log(CPOC_Title);
            console.log(CostCenter_ID);

            var info = {
                Leader_ID: CPOC_Title,
                CostCenter_ID: CostCenter_ID
            };

            var URL = getBaseURL() + 'DBO/DeptLeader_GetCurrent';
            console.log(URL);
            var DeptLeaders;
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: URL,
                data: JSON.stringify(info),
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response !== 'undefined' && typeof (response) == 'object') {
                    DeptLeaders = response.data;
                    console.log(DeptLeaders);
                    return DeptLeaders;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('ERROR:');
                    console.log(response);
                    return 'No Options Found';
                }
            });
        },
    };
}]);
```

**DBO Controller: Server-Side**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeptLeader_GetCurrent(string Leader_ID, string CostCenter_ID)
{
    try {
        List<SelectListItem> DL = DB.DeptLeader_GetByIDs(Leader_ID, CostCenter_ID);
        return Json(DL, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
         string error = e.ToString();
         return null;
     }
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DropDown_GetList(Sections section, DropDownFields field)
{
    return Json(DB.GetDropDownValues(section, field), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
<div ng-app="LineModule" ng-controller="LineCtrl" class="container col-md-12">
    ...
    <select ng-model="Type_ID" class="form-control" required>
        <option ng-value="T.Value" ng-repeat="T in Types">{{T.Text}}</option>
    </select>
    ...
    <select ng-model="CPOC_Title" class="form-control" ng-change="get_DeptLeader()">
        <option ng-value="D.Value" ng-repeat="D in DeptLeaders">{{D.Text}}</option>
    </select>
    {{SelectedLeader}}
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: did you try to put a break point on your `try catch` to see if there's an exception thrown ?

Comment: maybe it's because `Leader_ID` and `CostCenter_ID` are sent as an `int` and the server is expecting a `string` for both of them

Comment: 500. is server error, You cant do anything. Ask your backend guy.

Comment: For problem one your issues is likely related to Async. It would help to wait  on loading the page until the results have been returned. Something like $scope.isLoaded = false, when the post is complete set $scope.isLoaded = true.

Comment: Taki - I have a break point on the `catch` and it's also not being hit.
Taki - I tried changing the code to int and the ctrl was still not hit in the try or the catch.
Ved - I am the backend dev / full stack dev.

Comment: reed - When do I set .isLoaded to true?

Comment: Hit up the network tab in chrome tools and check the call by clicking on it you can actually see what went wrong. There will be some IIS error return.

Comment: @swallis1 are you able to resolve the issue. if yes, Please share the resolution to fix the 500 internal error for post.